# How can I read bootstrap source code?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have found Bootstrap useful, but I do not know how to read articulated source code. I have tried Chrome inspect but it is in bulk and so hard to read. Could anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

I assume you tried with the minified version of bootstrap which is compiled to a single file and not readable. Please download the source code. To download source code you can download by forking from [github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap). In the SCSS folder you will find the styles. I think this is what you are looking for.

Another way is to download with npm. If you have NodeJS installed in your computer, init a blank project with command `npm init` or `npm init -y` and install bootstrap along with source code with this command `npm install bootstrap`. When done you will find the source code in `node_modules/bootstrap` folder.